# Is the following quote from the Kite Runner an allusion or metaphor?

Tags: meaning, literary-device

And the cleft lip, just left of midline, where
the Chinese doll maker’s instrument may have slipped; or perhaps he had simply
grown tired and careless.

Comment: Is this an actual doll or a living person? If a doll, then neither; if a living person, then metaphor.

Comment: More context would be helpful. As a standalone, it looks like neither is present.

Comment: @Liam Noronha 'He kicked the bucket' is the classic example of context being vital.

Answer (score 4):

It's an extended simile. The author is comparing a character's appearance to a doll.

"I can still see Hassan up on that tree, sunlight flickering through the leaves on his almost perfectly round face, a face LIKE [caps mine] a Chinese doll chiseled from hardwood: his flat, broad nose and slanting, narrow eyes like bamboo leaves, eyes that looked, depending on the light, gold, green, even sapphire...and the cleft lip, just left of midline, where the Chinese doll maker's instrument may have slipped, or perhaps he had simply grown tired and careless"